# Раздвигающееся фото с выплываюшим текстом

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, animate

Возник такой вопрос (сам гуглил, но не могу додуматься даже как это назвать)

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на картинку она делилась пополам и из центра появлялся текст в рамке (пример можете увидеть на картинке)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно задать двум блокам, находящимся друг над другом, одну и ту же фотографию в качестве фона, подобрав нужный `background-position`. Между этими блоками разместить невидимой блок с текстом.

Comment: как вариант но я пчему то был уверен что можно используя 1 блок можно такого добиться

Answer (score 6):

```js
var bool = true
$('.image').click(function() {
  if (bool) {
    $('.block').animate({
      opacity: '1',
      height: '90'
    }, 500)
    $('#m').animate({
      top: "+=90px"
    }, 500)
    bool = false
  } else {
    $('.block').animate({
      opacity: '0',
      height: '0'
    }, 500)
    $('#m').animate({
      top: "-=90px"
    }, 500)
    bool = true
  }

})
```

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://lepser.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/osnovy-kompozicii-v-fotografii-big-03.jpg');
}
.block {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image" style="z-index:4;"></div>
<div class="block">Текст</div>
<div class="image" id="m" style="z-index:5;top:450px;background-position:0px 450px"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Я сделал на `hover`, а не на `click`. Но это можно переделать на `click` с помощью JavaScript, применяя на `click` те же стили что и у меня лежат в псевдоклассах `hover`.

Для `hover` это можно сделать на чистом CSS с помощью одного элемента.
Допустим размеры изображения 200x200:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-popup,
.image-popup:before,
.image-popup:after {
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}

.image-popup {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;

  /* Прячем элемент */
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.image-popup:before,
.image-popup:after {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px; /* Половина высоты изображения */
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px; /* Величина border исходного изображения */
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmtZb.jpg") no-repeat;
}

.image-popup:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%); /* Помещаем пол-картинки над элементом */
}

.image-popup:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%); /* Помещаем пол-картинки под элементом */
  background-position: 0 100%; /* Отображаем нижнюю половину картины */
}

/* Теперь делаем элемент видимым, установливая border, padding, heigth, font-size */
.image-popup:hover {
  border: 5px solid lime;
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* Стили если есть границы (border) */
.image-popup:hover:before {
  top: -5px;
}

.image-popup:hover:after {
  bottom:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-popup">
  WHO WE ARE
</div>
```

Comment: еще бы хорошо transition добавить

Comment: @G.Denis Вы правы, так более гладкий переход. Добавил.

Comment: @ Vadim Ovchinnikov  Прекрасное решение! Оригинально выглядит. Совершенству нет предела - убрать бы подергивание, когда курсор покидает картинку до окончания анимации. Другими словами запретить повторную анимацию пока не закончилась первая анимация по ховеру.

Comment: @Alexandr_T Спасибо за внимание и критику. Посмотрите сейчас, надеюсь исправил.

Comment: @ Vadim Ovchinnikov Отлично! Лучше, наверное невозможно сделать.